# Select a field by filter base on nest and sub nest document like Post->Comment->Likes using mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da7c114753c6202f4f4d3b2"),

    "image" : "hem sopheap-1571275028119.jpg",
    "body" : "my first post\r\nyes this my post",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-10-17T00:59:18.901Z"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e",
            "fullname" : "hem sopheap",
            "username" : "sopheap",
            "comment" : "My first comment",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5da7c125753c6202f4f4d3b4"),
            "replies" : []
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044",
            "fullname" : "soeng kanel",
            "username" : "",
            "comment" : "Mr. kansael comment",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5da8557f886aee13e4e7f045"),
            "replies" : [],
            "date" : ISODate("2019-10-17T10:10:37.394Z"),
            "likes" : [ 
             "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e", 
             "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6f"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 41,
    "likes" : [ 
            "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e", 
            "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6p"
        ]
}
```

I want to get all `likes` of  a specific `comments` not like of `post`
something similar like this in SQL statement:

```
db.posts.find({
  "comments": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "_id": ObjectId("5da8557f886aee13e4e7f045")
    }
  }
}, {
  likes:"$comments", _id:0
}).pretty()
```

and the expected result should be like this

`"likes" : [ 
            "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e", 
            "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6f"
        ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read about [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html)

Here's the complete query for you

```js
db.posts.find({
  "comments": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "user": "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044",
      "_id": ObjectId("5da8557f886aee13e4e7f045")
    }
  }
}, {
  likes:"$comments.likes", _id:0
}).pretty()
```

**Explanation:**

A common mistake people do when filtering based on multiple fields of array subdocuments is to simply do something like `{"comments._id": "something", "comments.user": "something"}` which returns all the items of array subdocument wherever some item matched to id, user. The solution to this problem is [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html)

Comment: I have updated query to format the output as you asked `likes: [id]`. Are you getting the right results? 
P.S. Please upvote if this helps you solve your problem. And accept answer if this solves the problem.

Comment: but there are many likes or many elements, I can only get one like from your query. can help more, to get the list of element under `likes`, can help to check my sample input data.